# React's props with the same name as their value

Tags: reactjs

Can we pass props to a component that has the same name and value implicitly?

Example:
Let's say that I have a variable called `x`: `const x = 1`;
and I have a component that has a prop called `x`. Can I pass it this variable as value implicitly? like that: `<div x/>`?

Comment: Usually, if you pass like that, the value x will be treated as a boolean value and the value of x will be true instead of the value you gave. Can you share us the example which you saw ?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Booleans can be passed implicitly to the component as @Ajay also pointed out in comments, like

```
<div x />
```

which is basically equivalent to

```
<div x={true} />
```

However, if your variable is something other than a boolean, then you need to write it like

```
<div x={x} />
```

Or if you have a number of such props, you can form an object like

```
const cmpProps = {
   x,
   y,
   foo,
   bar
}
```

and pass them using Spread attributes like

```
<Comp {...cmpProps} />
```

Comment: `<Comp {...{x}} />`
`<Comp {...{x,y,foo,bar}} />`

Comment: I have been using this syntax as I think it is cleaner in most cases, but was wondering if anyone knows if there is a performance implication when spreading vs passing same name props? e.g. `<Comp {...{ x, y }} />` vs `<Comp x={x} y={y} />`

Comment: Wondering wether {...{foo}} is considered to be better than foo={foo}. I feel like it reduces verbosity but at the same time the curly brackets and dots make it look weird.

Comment: I use it when there's multiple (like 4+) parameters. There could be a minor performance implication (depending on how transpiler handles it) but it would be negligible anyway.

Comment: @Curt no there's no performance implication, you can try both notations and check babel output, it will be the same (or rather `createElement(Comp, {x})` instead of `createElement(Comp, {x: x})`).

Answer (score 59):

I had a slight epiphany when reading these answers. Since in ES6+ you can add an existing variable to an object like this:

```
const x = 42;
const obj = { x, y: 1337 };
console.log(obj); // result { x: 42, y: 1337 }
```

That means you can add a named prop to a React component like:

```
const x = 42;
const elm = <MyComponent {...{x}} />;
```

Comment: This is a great solution.

Comment: +1 for this. I had the same thought myself. In my case 
`<DifficultySelector {...{ difficultyView, setDifficultyView }} />`

Comment: Heavily worth noting this clones the prop every time. This could be expensive if the prop is a nested object and re-renders frequently.

Comment: @temporary_user_name So would it be best to avoid the spread version in general then if performance is a factor?

Comment: @temporary_user_name there is no cloning, it compiles to exactly the same React.createElement call.

Comment: The expression `{...{x}}` is absolutely cloning `{x}`. It's creating a new object with the same properties as `{x}`. This has nothing to do with React or how React is compiled; that is a vanilla JS expression. I do however agree that the performance cost here is very unlikely to be noticeable except in extreme situations.

Comment: @temporary_user_name Of course it has to do with how things are compiled, things like `{...{x}}` can obviously be noticed by a compiler like Babel. JSX is not executed directly. As riv said, you're wrong. Cheers. I would paste the link to the Babel playground but it does not fit here.

Answer (score 11):

You can't, a prop with no assigned value (`<div x />`) is a shortener for (`<div x={true} />`) (as Ajay Varghese pointed out);

Passing the same variable name would be `<div x={x} />`

If you need to pass multiple values directly in JSX props you can use the [JSX Spread Attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes).

```
const divProps = { x: 1, y: 2 };
...
<div {...divProps} />
```

It is often used to pass all props from parent to children.

You can also override a prop by assigning it after the spread :

```
<div {...divProps} x=3 />
```